# Uncaught TypeError: Value is not of type AudioBuffer

Tags: audio, web, xmlhttprequest, audiobuffer

I get this error when I try to run an XHR to load a sample. Uncaught TypeError: Value is not of type AudioBuffer. Everything seems to be right, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
Kit.prototype.load = function(){
    if(this.startedLoading)
        return;
    this.startedLoading = true;

    // var kick = "samples/M-808Sn2.wav";
    var snare = "samples/M-808Sn2.wav";
    // var hihat = "samples/M-808Sn2.wav";

    // this.loadSample(0, kick, false);
    this.loadSample(1, snare, false);
    // this.loadSample(2, hihat, false);
}
```

I start it off with the request:

```
Kit.prototype.loadSample = function(sampleID, url, mixToMono){
// Load Asynchronously

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

var kit = this;

request.onload = function(){

    var buffer;
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(decodedBuffer){
        buffer = decodedBuffer;
    });

    switch(sampleID){
        // case 0: kit.kickBuffer = buffer; break;
        case 1: kit.snareBuffer = buffer; break;
        // case 2: kit.hihatBuffer = buffer; break;
    }
}

request.send();
```

}

Then I try to run it.

```
 context = new webkitAudioContext();


var kit = new Kit();

kit.load();

var voice = context.createBufferSource();

voice.buffer = kit.snareBuffer;
voice.loop = true;
voice.playbackRate.value = 1;
voice.connect(gain);

voice.start(0);
voice.stop(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `kit.load()` fires off an asynchronous request to load and decode the audio buffers. The two lines that follow (`createBufferSource`, assign the buffer) follow the asynchronous request immediately, whether or not the files have been loaded. So the reason you're getting this "Value is not of type `AudioBuffer`" is because at the time you assign `voice.buffer = kit.snareBuffer`, `kit.snareBuffer` is still undefined because the load callback hasn't fired.

The reason this probably works with `window.onload` is because the XHR request can run before the window has loaded, which means that by the time the `window.onload` event handler is fired, the XHR request has already come back and `kit.snareBuffer` is a defined `audioBuffer`.

This answer is coming a little late, but hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a regression in chrome. Even I am getting same error. See below chrome bug

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128826

Comment: wrapped it in an `window.onload = init;` that fixed it for me.