# TypeError: Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': The provided value is not of type 'AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, codepen

I am working on the existing [codoCircle](https://live.codecircle.com/d/yRDTQGf3tXXMjJtA5). Put the volume down.

It works out as expected.

Now i want to use the same code here in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/RVRqrj?editors=1010) and i get this error

*TypeError: Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': The provided value is not of type 'AudioBuffer*

I did a bit of research and i have found the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825030/uncaught-typeerror-value-is-not-of-type-audiobuffer) useful.

The answer says

At the time i assign in the `playSound` `player.buffer = buffer`, buffer is still undefined because the load callback hasn't fired.

This makes sense to me, so then i have tried to do a
`setTimeout` like:

```
setTimeout(playSound, 9000);
```

It did not work out.

Do you know any workaround for this? And why in CodeCircle works and not in Codepen?

Comment: get the same error with pixi-audio.js library, locally all worked as expected, but when uploaded to server, one mp3 file, in one place gives me that error (and it's downloads from server correctly). Have no idea why, please post answer if you find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> his makes sense to me, so then i have tried to do a setTimeout like ..

That's more a quickfix, but tricky as you don't know for sure if everything is loaded.

The solution is to wait until every sample is loaded. The best way is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for that, but that needs a (large) refactor and [isn't compatible with all the current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) (so you need then [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) etc).

So I made a easier approach: for every sample I have created a `boolean` variable that will be set to `true` when loading has finished (in the callback function)

```
var loadedHat = false;
var loadedSnare = false;
var loadedBd = false;

loadSample('cl_hat_3001.wav', function (buffer) {
    hat = buffer;
    loadedHat = true;
    startWhenAllLoaded();
});
loadSample('brp_snrim1.wav', function (buffer) {
    snare = buffer;
    loadedSnare = true;
    startWhenAllLoaded();

});
loadSample('bd08.wav', function (buffer) {
    bd = buffer;
    loadedBd = true;
    startWhenAllLoaded();
});
```

Then I wrapped your code to start in a `start` function and made a `startWhenAllLoaded`, which starts when all the tree booleans are `true`

```
function startWhenAllLoaded()
{
    if(!started && loadedHat && loadedSnare && loadedBd){
        started = true;
        start();
    }
}
```

The edited codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjdEzY?editors=1010)

NB: Not sure if everything works now OK, the error is gone but I think the code need some tweaking

Comment: TypeScript is great. Can recommend. It's becoming an industry standard for backend JavaScript as well.